# Tooltip for Talkative/Outspoken badge indicators in moderator dashboard not capitalized

Tags: bug, badges, moderator-tools, tooltips, capitalization

The moderator dashboard has two indicators, a bronze and a silver dot, which are shown if the moderator has the [Talkative](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/130/talkative) resp. [Outspoken](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/138/outspoken) badge. People have questioned their usefulness before ([1](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/246558/295232), [2](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/367936/295232)), but if we keep them (which is fine IMHO, they don't cause any harm), can we at least employ proper capitalization of the badge names?

[image]

Comment: Given that this is something that's shown only to moderators and is only about moderators (well, OK, it's also shown to employees and they get a display about all active users), I'm struggling to see that it's all that beneficial to allocate developer resources to this change, unless it's part of reworking substantial parts of that page, [as contemplated by Shog9 back in 2015](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/246560/271271). Basically, it's not something that's going to confuse a bunch of people, so "meh".

Comment: @Makyen true; OTOH this is probably one of the cases where it takes longer to write a bug report than to fix the issue. Long live CI/CD :)

Comment: Given that it took 4 years for [this feature request](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/319128/3773011) to be implemented, which was a trivial text change (also requested as a bug [here](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/321895/3773011)), and the lack of change was substantially contributing to making two entire review queues useless (i.e. it had a substantial impact), that type of argument (i.e. "it's a quick easy change") really isn't valid for Stack Exchange. While they have improved and *are* doing a bit better now, it's not to the point where that argument is consistent with how things get handled.

Comment: There is something wrong with the process if such a change results in too much overhead. Perhaps it could be batched up with other similar changes (e.g., a simple list that is applied in a batch manner every few months). I have reduced the overhead of updating [my list](https://pmortensen.eu/EditOverflow/_Wordlist/EditOverflowList_latest.html), so it is reasonable to do it on a daily basis (including some input validation and [some automation](https://github.com/PeterMortensen/Edit_Overflow/blob/main/Dot_NET_commandLine/Linux.sh)).